# Is it possible to nest dataclass in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I'm trying to achieve similar data class definition like the following C one:

```c
struct A {
  int b;
  struct {
     int d;
  } c; 
};
```

According to Dmitry Jemerov it is possible, but he didn't provide any code sample.
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/is-there-a-reason-for-not-allowing-inner-data-classes/2526/5

> You can simply make it nested inside another class. Nested classes can be data classes.

How it should be done if it is true?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**No, Kotlin does not support anonymous structures like that.**

You can both literally nest the classes:

```
data class A(
    val b: Int,
    val c: C
) {
    data class C(
        val d: Int
    )
}
```

Or use a more common syntax:

```
data class C(
    val d: Int
)

data class A(
    val b: Int,
    val c: C
)
```

Actually, there is no need in "nesting" here. The difference will be mostly in the way you access the `C` class: `A.C` or just `C`.

Comment: You mean that it is not possible to do it with "anonymous data class" like the C case?

Comment: No, Kotlin does not support anonymous structures like that.